# Error when running pip list (modulenotfounderror no module named 'pip._internal.utils')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm having problem whenever I try to run the `pip list`. Here is the traceback of my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 33, in <module> sys.exit(load_entry_point('pip==19.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'pip')())
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
        return next(matches).load()
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 77, in load
        module = import_module(match.group('module'))
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        import pip._internal.utils.inject_securetransport  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.utils'
```

Can anybody explain me why this error occurs and provide some help?

Comment: could you also insert the code?

Comment: Hi, I just ran "pip list" on my cmd and that shows up. Normally, it would show up a list of packages but in my case, only the above error showed up.

Comment: If you have the updated pip and it still shows the same error then I would suggest re-installing python, that should solve the problem.

Comment: I have just found this command but it's for ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'. idk is it work but I will try it first ! "curl bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py 
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

I tried this and it solved so I will just leave this here for future references!